# Import settings in one installation of IE10 to another?

Tags: windows-7, java, internet-explorer-10

Is there a way I can port over all settings (not just favorites, feeds, and cookies) from one IE install to another? I am having a problem where some users cannot get a webpage to display properly when zooming while at least one can.

The account that works is an admin account, but other admin accounts do not work. All accounts I am testing are using the latest version of java and windows 7 64-bit.

I have used gpedit.msc to generate text files of the security settings in both, and they are identical. Is there a way to easily compare everything as well?

Thank you

Comment: No;  IE does not this kind of exporting.

Comment: I know IE doesn't have an inbuilt functionality for what I want, but I was wondering if there was another way to do it? Or at least compare the total installs?

Comment: If you have a single machine that is causing the problem, I would just wipe the machine, and restore the default configuration that does work.  This assume you use deployable images.

Comment: It is account based. The account that works will work across multiple machines.

Comment: Some of the data is connected to the profile ( i.e. recovery session, saved session ) most of the settings are system wide stored by the registry and handled by group policy though.  Have you tried to reset the IE installation on the computer that isn't working?